# Monitor disk and network now Heapster is deprecated

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

Now that Heapster is nearing end of life, using the in incubation Metrics Server allows the "core" resources of CPU and Memory, is there a non-deprecated way of accessing other resource metrics (disk and network usage, for example) WITHOUT resorting to Prometheus?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/) is becoming standard de-facto for monitoring Kubernetes cluster.

> **When does it fit?**
> Prometheus works well for recording any purely numeric time series. It fits both machine-centric monitoring as well
> as monitoring of highly dynamic service-oriented architectures. In a
> world of microservices, its support for multi-dimensional data
> collection and querying is a particular strength.
>
> Prometheus is designed for reliability, to be the system you go to
> during an outage to allow you to quickly diagnose problems. Each
> Prometheus server is standalone, not depending on network storage or
> other remote services. You can rely on it when other parts of your
> infrastructure are broken, and you do not need to setup extensive
> infrastructure to use it.
>
> **When does it not fit?**
> Prometheus values reliability. You can always view what statistics are available about your system, even
> under failure conditions. If you need 100% accuracy, such as for
> per-request billing, Prometheus is not a good choice as the collected
> data will likely not be detailed and complete enough. In such a case
> you would be best off using some other system to collect and analyze
> the data for billing, and Prometheus for the rest of your monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `metrics-server` for some basic monitoring. Looks like it is the default tool. It integrates with `kubectl top`.

You can install metrics-server using helm from stable as follows:

`helm install stable/metrics-server`

You can also install it by other means if you don't use helm. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/eks/latest/userguide/metrics-server.html) are some installation docs from Amazon EKS.